# Cell looks empty in Excel. But in pandas it display as '\n-'

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

Goal: Remove all of these '\n-' that you can see on the [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5byY.png). I have tried to do df.dropna() but it did not work. This is how that column looks in excel [Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCeqe.png). Just looks like an empty cell?

I have tried to search online I was not able to find an answer.

Comment: Your two pictures are the same. That `\n` makes me think the cell contains a line-feed character which wouldn't be visible to the naked eye in excel.

Comment: look for df.replace, so you need to replace newline and hypen with ""(space)

Comment: Please note the [docs for dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and the examples they show. Dropna is to  "Remove missing values." The values you included are not missing or `NaN`, they're just a specific _string_ value

Comment: My Question is how to get rid of it. I need it to be empty?

Comment: @Jnevill I was able to remove the space and the - but dropna still does not work? But it just looks empty.

Comment: Thanks Jnevill it works. If you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: `dropna` is just for removing `NaN` which is different then an empty value/string. Are you wanting to remove any row that contains that empty string now like `df[~df.yourcolumn.str.contains("")]` or whatever?

Comment: Yes, that's right, JNevill. That what I am trying to do now. But I tried df[~df.yourcolumn.str.contains("")] it did not work.

Comment: It is interesting because NaN cells appear in Excel as an empty string. And for me after doing the above steps. It still won't handle it as NaN? Even dough it displays as empty string?

Comment: Thanks, everyone for your help. I figure out the solutiion on how to convert empyt strings to NaN. Do it with df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.NaN, regex=True).